# Cisco APIC node BGP info via CLI/SSH

Tags: cisco

Here is how to get BGP info in a host in Cisco APIC via GUI/HTTPS.

```
APIC > Fabric > Inventory > POD 1 > (any) Host > Protocol > BGP
```

This image is taken from http://cdn.techgenix.com/media/promos/APIC-Fabric.JPG

Therefore, I can't expand the `POD 1` and browse to `(any) Host > Protocol > BGP`

[image]

Would it possible to get the same info via CLI/SSH?

If yes, what is the command?

Comment: There are a multitude of BGP show commands on a Cisco router.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin, I've updated the question above by providing some image that I found on internet. If you have APIC, you can browse to that path, and I would like to get information displayed there via CLI/SSH, and not via GUI/HTTPS

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do basically anything that can be done from the GUI via either API calls or the NXOS CLI.  Take a look at the various show commands [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/4-x/cli/nxos/cr421/Cisco-APIC-NXOS-CLI-Command-Reference-421/Cisco-APIC-NXOS-CLI-Command-Reference-421_chapter_010100.html) to get started.  There's also a hyperlink to an index with every available CLI command.